# Embedded Jetty and REST interface issue

Tags: java, jetty, jax-rs, cxf

I am just working on simple server that is based on embedded Jetty, Spring and mongo. I expose simple rest interface for clients. Server is working correctly on Windows platform but when I wanted to run it on Linux something strange happened. When I try to call any REST API on server i get following error.

```
WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /sensor/update/
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:253)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can not figure out what is a reason of this situation. What is really strange same jar is working correctly on Windows platform but on Linux not. 
I start server by java -jar server.jar.
I tried to run it on Raspberry PI and CentOS and it always throw NullPointerException while calling REST API by client. 
I update all dependencies in pom to the newest version of all libraries and it doesn't help. Is anybody encounter similar problem?

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Run `cd /path/to/myjettbase && java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist.jar --list-config` on both systems and compare the results (esp the xml section at the bottom)

Comment: is it applicable to built in jetty or standalone version? I'am asking because i running jetty inside my app server.

Comment: you say "I start server by java -jar server.jar" so i'm assuming you are using jetty-distribution and have setup proper `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` directories, per the documentation (or heeding the warnings when you don't follow the documentation)

Comment: server.jar is my application. I don't have jetty on Linux likewise on Windows. Jetty is in my jar file with other required libraries.